# ディレクトリプログラミング言語

Tags: プログラミング言語

システムディレクトリを書くためにどのようなプログラミング言語が使用されていますか？また、GUIが存在する前にディレクトリが存在しましたか？

Comment: ファイルシステムを実装している言語、ということでしょうか？

Comment: それが私が求めていることです.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## ファイルシステムを実装する言語

ファイルシステムはOSの機能の一つであるため、通常C言語かアセンブリのいずれかが使用されています。

参考:LinuxのファイルシステムはすべてCで実装されているようです。 https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/fs/

## GUIが存在する前にディレクトリが存在したか？

**はい。**

最初にディレクトリ（当初はfolderという名前でした）というメタファーを提示したのが
ERMA (Electronic Recording Machine, Accounting)というプロジェクトであり、こちらは1950年から1955年まで活動していたようです。

[Directory (computing) - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_%28computing%29#Folder_metaphor)
[Electronic Recording Machine, Accounting - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_Recording_Machine,_Accounting)

一方、最初のGUIと言えるNLSは1960年代に開発、1968年に販売しており、こちらが一歩出遅れた形であるようです。
[History of the graphical user interface - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_graphical_user_interface#Augmentation_of_Human_Intellect_%28NLS%29)
[NLS (computer system) - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NLS_%28computer_system%29)